# Change starting position in lodash map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I need to map an array starting from index `1`, not `0`. How can I do this using [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map)? Here's what I have so far:

```
function getStoryCard(value, key) {
    return {
        imageSection: storyCardMedia[OVERVIEW_DRAWERS_CONSTANTS.STORYCARD + key],
        linkOut: value.Link || null,
        subTitle: value.Subtitle || null,
        title: value.Title || null,
        viewMore: value.ViewMore ? getViewMore(value.ViewMore) : null,
        type: storyCardType
    }
}

// This method gets an object array
// [Object, Object....]
storyCards = _.map(pickedCards, getStoryCard);

// Set index to 1, but map method already has executed
for (var i = 1; i <= storyCards.length; i++) {

    if (storyCards.imageSection === undefined) {
        storyCards.splice(0, 1);
    }

    storyCards[i];
}

return storyCards;
```

Comment: why do you need to start at 1? `.map` is a 1 to 1 function.

Comment: do you need `.filter`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the slice function that's on arrays before calling map.

Off the top of my head I believe

```
arr.slice(1)
```

will give you the array minus the first entry.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [rest()](https://lodash.com/docs#rest)?

```
storyCards = _.map(_.rest(pickedCards), getStoryCard);
```

Answer (score 1):

[_.map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) *is* passing you the index - it only provides keys when you pass in an object, and since you're passing in an array, you're solid.

However, unlike `filter`, `map` always inserts a value into the returned array, even if that value is something like `undefined` (if you decide to return at index 0). Thus, you'd end up with something like [`undefined`, {}, {}, {}]. Not good.

One way you could solve this would be to use another lodash method, `compact`. Compact simply iterates through an array removes falsey values. Your above code sample would then become:

```
function getStoryCard(value, index) {
    imageSection = storyCardMedia[OVERVIEW_DRAWERS_CONSTANTS.STORYCARD + index];

    if (!imageSection || index === 0) return;       

    return {
        imageSection: imageSection,
        linkOut: value.Link || null,
        subTitle: value.Subtitle || null,
        title: value.Title || null,
        viewMore: value.ViewMore ? getViewMore(value.ViewMore) : null,
        type: storyCardType
    }
}

return _.compact(_.map(pickedCards, getStoryCard));
```

We iterate through `pickedCards`, accepting those cards we wish to. Those cards we don't want to insert simply become `undefined` in the array, which `compact` will subsequently remove. Hope this helps!